# How to save session data in to text box value?

Tags: php, session

I have some data in a session and I want to save it in text box value, using PHP. But the problem is when saving, just first token of string will be saved, like below example:

```
 <?php session_start();?>

<html >
<head>  
</head>

<body>
    <form >
        <?php echo $_SESSION['institute']="rebaz salih" ?>
        <input type="text" <?php  echo "value=".$_SESSION['institute']; ?>  required />     
    </form>
</body>
```

Output will be:

```
rebaz salih
rebaz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['institute']="rebaz salih" ?>
```

Is this supposed to be the assignment? or just a print line? in any case, try getting rid of the echo.

Both @edCoder, and @chethan194 are on the right track... the value belongs on the outside, but you really should be using a new variable for institute. For example:

```
//htmlspecialchars will clear out any quotes, etc so it will work in the browser.
<?php 
    $value = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['institute'], ENT_QUOTES);
?>
<form >
    <input type="text" value = "<?php print $value; ?>" required />     
</form>
```

Here is the full example:

```
<?php
     php session_start();
     //i don't know where you get the institute, so i will leave it here for now...
     $_SESSION['institute']="rebaz salih";
     $value = '';
     if (!empty($_SESSION['institute']))
     {
         $value = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['institute'], ENT_QUOTES);
     }
?>
<html>
<head>  
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" value = "<?php print $value; ?>" required />    
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok. Not a problem. Please accept the answer then by clicking on the checkmark beside my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can put the value attribute outside php

```
    <?php echo $_SESSION['institute']="rebaz salih" ?>
      Wrong -  <input type="text" <?php  echo "value=".$_SESSION['institute']; ?> />       
    Right -  <input type="text" value = "<?php  echo $_SESSION['institute'];?>"  />     
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['institute']; ?>" required/>
```